# Icon as select component in ionic v1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework v1. I want a `more` icon to get displayed for every element in the list on the right side of the list item. When user clicks on the more icon, he should see a drop-down with two option - approve and reject.
Both the options should be clickable and will call a function to perform some tasks.
How can I achieve this?
There are solutions for ionic v2 but not for ionic v1

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
      <ion-item ng-click="show = !show" class="item-icon-right">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b">
        {{item.text}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item ng-show="show" ng-click="firstFunction()">
        Approve
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item ng-show="show" ng-click="secondFunction()">
        Reject
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/nuovo001/pen/jwWzQK

Comment: @rohanagarwal I have update my answer with an example

Comment: nice effort, but i meed a dropdown like effect, not just two more entries of list getting displayed

Comment: Ok I hadn't understood. Probably [cordova actionsheet plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-actionsheet) could help you